# Rails 4.1.1 Devise auth signup and update account buttons don't work

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm developing an application that uses the devise gem to provide authentication for the user model. A while ago I decided to implement an Admin class also using devise, instead of putting an admin:boolean onto the existing user model. After I did this, for some reason the standard user sign up and update account buttons stopped working.

The only thing I changed on the standard devise user forms was to add a link to 'admin login' on the sign in view (which still worked) to the devise admin sign in page. Both the sign in pages worked.

Now here's the thing, both the sign up and update account buttons worked after a page refresh.

I have since removed the Admin class and resorted to using a boolean on the User model, but the problem persists. Additionally, the problem is present when I run locally in dev mode, on a staging production environment on heroku and on our AWS Ubuntu testing instance.

I have been pulling my hair out for like three weeks over this, has anyone experienced a similar error?

Help. Please.

Using:

Rails 4.1.1

Devise 3.2.4

twitter-bootstrap-rails 2.2.8 (not using bootstrap themes on devise views though)

Code:

```
    <h2>Sign up</h2>

    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url =>         registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div><%= f.label :username %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :username, :autofocus => true %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :firstname %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :fname %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :lastname %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :lname %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :mobile %><br />
      <%= f.number_field :mobile %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>


      <p>You must read and accept My Company's <%= link_to "Terms and Conditions", '/home/terms' %> to register.</p>
      <%= f.label :tos_acceptance, "I accept" %>
      <%= check_box( :user, :tos_acceptance, {}, true, false )%></div><br>


      <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>


      <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
    <% end %>
```

NB: I'm certain this is a view error. I've also inspected the elements using chrome console, there is apparently no difference between the non refreshed button (doesn't work) and the refreshed button (which works). :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this, looks like the standard devise views were conflicting with bootstrap3 (or something).

Using the gem 'rails_layout' and running

`$ rails generate layout:devise bootstrap3`

rebuilt the view files, all I needed to do was add my custom fields back in and it worked perfectly.